# Calling a class and returning data?

Tags: c++

I'm a bit of a newbie, so some help here would greatly be appreciated. I have a class called Device which gets a devices screen size:

```
int Device::GetDisplay()
{
 DisplayInfo display;
 int displayArray [2];
 displayArray[0] = display.pixelSize().width();
 displayHeight[1] = display.pixelSize().height();

 return displayArray;
}
```

It returns an array, is there a better way to return the data?

Also is there a better way to call the class, It's currently called via:

```
Device *device = new Device();
device.GetDisplay();
```

Could I call it without using Device `*device = new Device();`

Thanks!

Comment: I'd make it static and return a data structure.

Comment: -1: How does that even compile? Even if the code were remotely valid, you can't "return an array" in C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `std::array<2, int> foo();` Eh, close enough.

Comment: What is `displayHeight`?

Comment: Please could you post the real code. And tell us how it is failing to meet your needs.

Comment: This is the real code. I just wanted some pointers about C++ the above works fine for me

Comment: The above works for you? Really? Your function with a return value of `int` is supposedly returning a *local* array.

Comment: @chris: An array as in the language-defined "array" types that the OP is talking about in the question, not the wrapper from the library. My point is that the OP has misled us about his existing code for some reason.

Comment: It's not the real code. The real code compiles. You've posted fake code. Post real code.

Comment: If you can't see that it's fake code by looking at it, and I know you are a novice so that's fair enough, you only have to try to compile it. Use the clipboard to be sure you are using the code in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could I call it without using Device *device = new Device();

Yes, you can instantiate it on [automatic storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable):

```
Device device;
```

You should only use dynamic allocation if you really need it. It isn't clear from your example that you need it at all.

As for the rest of the question, there are too many errors to make ant sense out of it. But you could return a simple class holding the two pieces of information you want:

```
struct DisplayDimensions
{
  int height;
  int width;
};

DisplayDimensions Device::GetDisplay()
{
 DisplayInfo display;
 DisplayDimensions d;
 d.width = display.pixelSize().width();
 d.height = display.pixelSize().height();

 return d;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what should I put in my header file so I can access GetDisplay from another class? What type should it return?

Comment: @user1013512 `GetDisplay` returns a `DisplayDimensions`, so you should put that either in its own header, or put the declaration/definition wherever the `Device` declaration/definition are, respectively.

Comment: @user1013512 he shows the return type in his answer right there. It sounds like you may want to work on some C++ tutorials or something to learn some of these basics.

Answer (score 0):

Your return value(`int`) does not match the value that returned from the function(`int[2]`), you should either use `std::array` or `std::pair` or something like that.

Since your function never use `this` you can make it `static` then you can call it without an instance of the class using `Device::GetDisplay()`.

You should first mark your function as `static`:

```
static std::pair<int, int> GetDisplay() {
    DisplayInfo display;
    return std::make_pair(display.pixelSize().width(), display.pixelSize().height());
}
```

Then you can use `Display::GetDisplay()`

Comment: Thanks, how can I make it static?

Comment: Make what static? The method?

Comment: Yes, so I can use it without an instance.

Comment: Ive tried Device::GetDisplay(); but I get the error: undefined reference to `Device::GetDisplay()' Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, last thing, how do I get just one part of the pair with: Display::GetDisplay(). Eg. just the height? Thanks

Comment: `std::pair<>` is all wrong here. What we have here is a `struct` containing members names `width` and `height`. With `std::pair<>` you need to name them `first` and `second` which lacks a lot. It's really no better than `int[2]`.